# Is Apache Spark recommended to run on windows?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement to run Spark on Windows in a production environment. I would like to get advice in understanding if Apache Spark on Windows is recommended. If not, I would like to know the reason behind the same.

Comment: Lack of official documentation, lower performance in some configurations (lack of `fork`), dozens of Windows specific issues, and permanently flaky Windows tests would be just a few reasons for "not". And that's on Spark side alone, with more problems to come if you're interested in broader ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation(official) from Apache Spark mentioned, it is not for windows? That will help me to add it when communicating with the customers.

Comment: I'd say that the official position is is the opposite - that Spark should work on Windows, so I wouldn't expect such documentation. It is simply that such deployment is a marginal case (no public provider nor major interested party uses Windows deployments AFAIK) and it comes with all the problems usual to such situation.